# Turn off 'Perforce change - o' command

Tags: perforce

I'm logged in with the Perforce viewer client on my MacBook Pro, and I keep getting this popup that says:

`You don't have permission to execute the "P4 change -o" command`

This happens ever 5 minutes or so. How do I turn this off?

Comment: Was this the "exact" error message? The 'p4 protects -u <username>' gives your set permissions which may need to be modified. What is the 'Perforce viewer client' - do you mean P4V?

Comment: @P4Shimada Yes, this was the exact message. And yes, I'm using P4V.

Answer (score 0):

The P4V client program will run certain commands as needed.  It is possible that your workspace specification could have something mapped in it that you do not have sufficient permissions to run this command on.  You can see what permissions are required for certain commands in the Server Administrator's Guide:  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.protections.html#DB5-35217 (the change command requires "open" access level).

You may wish to check with your server administrator to check what you do have access to and look at the client workspace mapping to see if there might be something mapped there that your user does not have sufficient permission to access.